# Cant click element in puppeteer: TypeError: product_page.click is not a function

Tags: javascript, xpath, puppeteer, element

I'm trying to find an element by it's xpath and i guess that's working, but to click the element is not working. I tested out to click the element in Selenium Python, with the same xpath and that's working, so the xpath is not the problem. This is the part of the code, that is not working:

```
await page.goto('THEWEBSITE')
const product_page = await page.$x('//*[@id="container"]/article[6]/div/h1/a');
await product_page.click()
```

I'm getting this Error:

```
await product_page.click()
                        
TypeError: product_page.click is not a function
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(product_page)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`page.$x()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagexexpression) returns an array of element handles. Try this to get the first element by array destructuring:

```js
await page.goto('THEWEBSITE');
const [product_page] = await page.$x('//*[@id="container"]/article[6]/div/h1/a');
await product_page.click();
```